# DataGrid area not filled with Cells

Tags: wpf, datagrid, contextmenu

How can I access DataGrid area not filled with Cells?

[image]

I want to add context menu for this area only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a ContextMenu to the DataGrid itself for the "Blank" area, but it will also appear for any rows you right-click on, if you don't have a different context menu assigned to the rows (or the "DataGrid.RowStyle" property).

The 'workaround' is to simply assign a different context menu to the rows, specifically.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Header="Menu Item in Blank Area" />
        </ContextMenu>
    </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Menu Item just for Populated Rows" />
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>   
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: the idea is to assign the same context menu to Cells and to the area not filled with Cells (marked as "this" on the picture). And other context menu to Header. Thats why I asked the question.

Comment: Please update your original question to reflect that.  The answer is still the same; you'll create a context menu for the <DataGrid> element (which will effect EVERYTHING in the DataGrid, including the empty area and cells), and assign a different one to the specific thing you want to override (in this case, the Header)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment to a previous answer, I see that you want to set one ContextMenu on your headers, and a separate one for your cells and empty space. I was able to set separate ContextMenus by overriding the Template:

```
<Window x:Class="Apc_System_Generator.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="cmenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="FOO" />
                    <MenuItem Header="BAR" />
                </ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Key="omenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="LOL" />
                    <MenuItem Header="WUT" />
                </ContextMenu>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <DataGrid Name="LOL" AutoGenerateColumns="True" ContextMenu="{StaticResource cmenu}">
            <DataGrid.Template>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <DataGridColumnHeadersPresenter Grid.Row="0" ContextMenu="{StaticResource omenu}" />
                        <DataGridRowsPresenter Background="gray" Grid.Row="1" IsItemsHost="True" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </DataGrid.Template>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```